# createJS - Random movement of multiple objects in container

Tags: javascript, random, createjs

I am using the code from this fiddle:

https://codepen.io/rauluranga/pen/KwoBdE

I would like to use this code to make each object in my enemies.container have random movement.

Code:

```
if(ticker2 > 80) {
xT2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*600) + 100;                
yT2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*400) + 100;
ticker2  = 0;
}
ticker2++;

xP2 += (xT2 - xP2)/15;
yP2 += (yT2 - yP2)/15;

wingman2.x += ((xP2 - wingman2.x)/60);
wingman2.y += ((yP2 - wingman2.y)/60);
```

What I tried so far:

making a for loop to loop over the enemies.length and create a new xT and yT numbers for each enemy:

```
if(ticker > 50) {

xT.length = 0;
yT.length = 0;

for(var count = 0; count < enemies.children.length; count++) {
xT.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*700) + 100);                
yT.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*500) + 100); 
}   
ticker = 0;
}
ticker++;
```

Now after that I got stuck on moving forward.

```
for(var count = 0; count < xT.length; count++) {

xP += (xT[count] - xP)/15;
yP += (yT[count] - yP)/15;

}

for(var count = 0; count <  enemies.children.length; count++) {

enemies.children[count].x += ((xP - enemies.children[count].x)/60);
enemies.children[count].y += ((yP - enemies.children[count].y)/60);

}
```

I tried making more forloops and array but with zero succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the properties directly to the enemies objects. This will make everything alot easier to understand and maintain.

```
function initEnemies(){
    for(var count = 0; count <  enemies.children.length; count++) {

        var enemy = enemies.children[count]

        enemy.targetX = 0
        enemy.targetX = 0

        enemy.moveX = 0
        enemy.moveY = 0

        enemy.ticker = 0

    }
}

function updateEnemies(){
    for(var count = 0; count <  enemies.children.length; count++) {

        var enemy = enemies.children[count]

        if(enemy.ticker>50){

            enemy.targetX = Math.ceil(Math.random()*600) + 100
            enemy.targetX = Math.ceil(Math.random()*600) + 100

            enemy.ticker = 0
        }
        enemy.ticker++

        enemy.moveX += (enemy.targetX - enemy.moveX)/15
        enemy.moveY += (enemy.targetY - enemy.moveY)/15

        enemy.x += (enemy.moveX - enemy.x)/60
        enemy.y += (enemy.moveY - enemy.y)/60
    }
}
```